# How can I access a variable inside a multi-step step definition?

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber

I am currently trying to define a multi-step step definition in Cucumber (for Ruby) but I'm having trouble using a variable in one of the sub-steps. Below I am trying to use the "policy_name" variable in the last sub step but can not get Cucumber to recognize it for its variable value, instead it keeps using it as a string.

```
 Given("I should NOT be able to go back using the browser back button 
 after doing something {string}") do |policy|

   step 'I click on "something"'
   step 'I "do this" via computer'
   step 'I click on the browser back button'

   policy_name = case policy
   when "policy1" then "something1"
   when "policy2" then "something2"
   end

   step 'I should be on the "Specified" page 
   for #{policy_name}'
 end
```

Comment: I should have mentioned this is using Cucumber for Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using single quote or double quotes? Double quotes allow for interpolation while single quotes will just use the contents without translating any variables. `"#{policy_name}"` should work, while `'#{any_variable}'` should not work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write steps like this and don't nest steps, you will just get into a mess. Also Given's are for setting up state, not for doing something.

If you have a complex step like this you have two better options than nesting steps

1. Break the step into simpler steps
2. Push the complexity down out of the step definitions and into helper methods

Having steps like "When I click something" is counter productive. That step is all about HOW something is done. Scenarios should be about WHAT you are doing and WHY its important. Features and scenarios are not for programming, they are for describing behaviour and should be very simple. So you should be writing something like

```
Scenario: When I foo then the back button is disabled
  Given ...
  When I foo
  Then the back button should be disabled
```

an example for my bank would be

```
Scenario: Smile login disables back button
  Given I am logged into smile banking
  When I try and use the back button
  Then I should see the back button disabled warning
```

Finally each step definition should just be a call to a helper method. e.g.

```
Given 'I am logged into smile banking' do
  # NOTE: both params are also helper methods
  login(site: smile_banking, user: create_user)
end
```

this allows you to push all the complexity out of cucumber and into code. Code can handle complexity, Cucumber cannot.